# RSA algorithm fails for some strings

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, rsa, pow

Exercise 11.7 from [Chapter 11 of Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/book012.html), by Allen B. Downey, prompts the following:

> Exponentiation of large integers is the basis of common algorithms for public-key encryption. Read the Wikipedia page on the RSA algorithm3 and write functions to encode and decode messages.

I translated the plain English algorithm from the [Key Generation section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation). The function `RSA` takes a string and encodes it as an ASCII integer, creates public and private keys for decryption, encrypts the encoded integer using the public keys, decrypts it using the private key, and then decodes the integer back into a string:

```
import math

def encode(s):

    m = ''
    for c in s:

        # each character in the message is converted to a ascii decimal value
        m += str(ord(c))

    return int(m)

def decode(i):
    # convert decrypted int back to string
    temp = str(i)
    decoded = ''
    while len(temp):
        if temp[:1] == '1':
            letter = chr(int(temp[:3]))
            temp = temp[3:]
        else:
            letter = chr(int(temp[0:2]))
            temp = temp[2:]
        decoded += letter
    
    return decoded

def generate_keys(m):

    # requires an int m that is an int representation (in ascii) of our message

    # 1. Choose two distinct prime numbers p and q.

    ##### TEST WIKIPEDIA EXAMPLE #####
    # p, q = 61, 53

    # find two prime numbers whose product n will be greater than m
    i = math.ceil(math.sqrt(m))
    primes = []
    while len(primes) < 2:
        if isPrime(i):
            primes += [i]
        i += 1
    p, q = primes[0], primes[1]

    # 2. Compute n = pq.
    n = p * q
    in_range = int(m) < n
    if not in_range:
        print('m must be less than n')
        exit()

    # 3. Compute λ(n), where λ is Carmichael's totient function. Since n = pq, λ(n) = lcm(λ(p),λ(q)), and since p and q are prime, λ(p) = φ(p) = p − 1 and likewise λ(q) = q − 1. Hence λ(n) = lcm(p − 1, q − 1).
    # The lcm may be calculated through the Euclidean algorithm, since lcm(a,b) = |ab|/gcd(a,b).
    a, b = (p - 1), (q - 1)
    lam = int(abs(a * b) / math.gcd(a, b))
    # print('lam:', lam)

    # 4. Choose an integer e such that 1 < e < λ(n) and gcd(e, λ(n)) = 1; that is, e and λ(n) are coprime.

    ##### TEST WIKIPEDIA EXAMPLE #####
    # e = 17

    # accordng to wikipedia, the smallest (and fastest) possible value for e is 3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation
    i = 3

    while i < lam:
        if math.gcd(i, int(lam)) == 1:
            e = i
            break
        i += 1

    # 5. compute d where d * e ≡ 1 (mod lam)
    d = int(modInverse(e, lam))

    return {'public': [n, e], 'private': d}

def encrypt_message(m, public):

    n, e = public[0], public[1]

    # generate ciphertext
    return pow(m, e, n)

def decrypt_message(cipher, n, d):

    # decrypt ciphertext
    return pow(cipher, d, n)

def RSA(s):
    m = encode(s)
    keys = generate_keys(m)
    cipher = encrypt_message(m, keys['public'])
    message = decrypt_message(cipher, keys['public'][0], keys['private'])

    messages_match = message == m
    if not messages_match:
        print('the decoded integer does not equal the encoded integer')
        exit()

    return decode(message)

# taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-check-whether-a-number-is-prime-or-not/
def isPrime(n) : 
  
    # Corner cases 
    if (n <= 1) : 
        return False
    if (n <= 3) : 
        return True
  
    # This is checked so that we can skip  
    # middle five numbers in below loop 
    if (n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0) : 
        return False
  
    i = 5
    while(i * i <= n) : 
        if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0) : 
            return False
        i = i + 6
  
    return True

# modInverse(a, m) taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplicative-inverse-under-modulo-m/
def modInverse(a, m) : 
    m0 = m 
    y = 0
    x = 1
  
    if (m == 1) : 
        return 0
  
    while (a > 1) : 
  
        # q is quotient 
        q = a // m 
  
        t = m 
  
        # m is remainder now, process 
        # same as Euclid's algo 
        m = a % m 
        a = t 
        t = y 
  
        # Update x and y 
        y = x - q * y 
        x = t 
  
  
    # Make x positive 
    if (x < 0) : 
        x = x + m0 
  
    return x 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(RSA('python')) # encrypts and decrypts message 'python'
    print(RSA('cat')) # encrypts and decrypts message 'cat'
    print(RSA('dog')) # encrypts and decrypts message 'dog'
    print(RSA('a 1')) # (to rule out spaces as the culprit) encrypts and decrypts message 'a 1'
    print(RSA('pythons')) # FAILS - 7 characters in string seems to be the limit
    print(RSA('hello world')) # FAILS - encoded string does not equal decoded string
```

At the end of the script, I test `RSA` with several strings. The output equals the input for 'python', 'cat', 'dog', and 'a 1' (the intended behavior). But the encoded and decoded integers are different for 'pythons' and 'hello world'.

I suspect that it is the input string length that is causing the problem, but I'm not sure where that is causing the breakdown. My guess is that `pow(cipher, d, n)` in the function `decrypt_message` is returning an unexpected result if `cipher` is of too great a length.

Why does `RSA` work for some strings but not others? Is it the length of the input string or something else?

Comment: You have a bug in your code. In python, the single slash `/` represents *floating point* division, whereas the double slash `//` is for integer division. This line `lam = int(abs(a * b) / math.gcd(a, b))` is using the floating point division operator when it should be using the integer division operator `//`. Also, you are using the `int()` method superflously. When something is already an integer then `int()` basically does nothing, but it makes your code harder to read. Only its use in `encode()` seems to make sense.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you, that did the trick. I am still confused why using integer division solved the problem. If `lam = abs(a * b) / math.gcd(a,b)` we can reason that `lam` will be a whole number, no? If so, then why can't we convert the resulting float to an int without altering the value? Granted, I see why the same reasoning allows us to safely use integer division with this calculation (and that did solve my initial question). But why do the results begin to diverge?

Comment: Good question! Floats in python have 53 bits of precision, and integers between -2\*\*53 and 2\*\*53 can be represented exactly as floats. Beyond that, some integers cannot be represented exactly, so they are represented with a close approximation. This approximation is close enough for smaller values so that int() will return the correct value, but one m gets to be large enough that approximation is no longer close enough. In your case that occurs when m gets to be a 67 bit integer.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ahhh, ok, now it is making sense—thank you for the clear explanations!

Comment: In very short: if you're using floating point arithmetic to implement cryptographic algorithms then you're doing it wrong. You use integer for the smaller calculations, big integer for asymmetric crypto using big groups / numbers, and 32 / 64 bit words for binary ops in symmetric crypto. Python can use big integer without fuss, that's  a good thing (and a bit of a trap if you want to be secure against side channel attacks, possibly).

Comment: For `python >= 3.9` you may be interested with [math.lcm()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm)